# A Group of Order $540$ is not simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Why is a group of order $540$ not simple?  The hints I have been given are not helpful.

Here's what I have been told.

Let $G$ be such a group.  Then there are $36$ Sylow $5$-subgroups;  let $H$ be one of them.
Also, there are $10$ Sylow $3$-subgroups;  let $K$ be one of them.

Then $[G: N(H)] = 36$, whence $N(H)$ has order $15$;  also, $[G: N(K)] = 10$, whence $N(K)$ has order $54$.  We can show that $N(H)$ and $N(K)$ intersect in a subgroup of order $3$.

Then $N(N(H)\cap N(K))$ has order divisible by $45$.

All is fine up to here.

The next hint I get says that a group of order $45$ is abelian (which it indeed is).

But how does this solve the problem?

Comment: What is the order of the normalizer in N(N(H) intersect N(K)) of a Sylow 5-subgroup of N(N(H) intersect N(K))? [ Hint: it has two different answers. ]

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to your question, but just about groups of order 540 with 36 Sylow 5-subgroups: they all have a normal subgroup of order 108 by Burnside's transfer theorem.

Comment: Hint: There is a subgroup of order $9$ whose normalizer has order divisible by $135,$ so that normalizer has index dividing $4.$

Comment: This is not what you are looking for but,
since $(27)^2>|G|$, $O_3(G)>1$ then $G$ is not simple.

Comment: What is O3(G)?  I've never seen that notation.

Comment: http://www.math.wisc.edu/~jensen/Algebra/ThmsGroups.pdf 
In page $4$, exercise $7$, there is a solution of your problem.

Comment: $O_p(G)$ is the intersection of all sylow-$p$ subgroup.

Comment: @mesel: It is possible to have groups $G$ with $|P|^{2} > |G|$ for $P \in {\rm Syl}_{p}(G),$ yet $O_{p}(G) = 1.$ For example, there is a solvable group $G$ of order $64 \times 81$ with $O_{3}(G) =1.$

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: It works when $O_p(G)$ can be written as intersection of two sylow-$p$ and I remember a lemma that if a group have $3p+1$ sylow $p$ subgroup then  $O_p(G)$ can be written intersection of two sylows. (In that case, it has $10=3.3+1$).

Comment: @mesel: I think that Lemma is true when $p >3$ by a Theorem of Brodkey, since $G/O_{p}(G)$ will have Abelian Sylow $p$-subgroups. It may be true for $p =2,3$, but it requires some proof. In any case, I wanted to point out the general fact that the size of a Sylow $p$ being greater than $\sqrt{|G|}$ is not itself sufficient to give $O_{p}(G) > 1.$

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: you are right, it is not enough itself to conclude.

Comment: Why do $N(H)$ and $N(K)$ intersect in a subgroup of order 3 and not 1?

Answer (score 2):

*Hint in light of Jack's second comment:*

> Lemma: Let $G$ be a simple group and let $H< G$ such that $[G:H]=n$. Then $G\hookrightarrow A_n$.

Why we can use here. Because if $|G|<\infty$ and $H< G$ such that $[G:H]=n$ provided $|G|\nmid n!/2$ so $G$ is not simple. Now think of using this lemma while you're led to a subgroup of order $108$.