# Prove that a group of order $540$ is not simple

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, simple-groups

> Prove that a group of order $540$ is not simple

In this problem I have done the following steps.

Sylow's Theorem  gives $n_3=10$ and $n_5=36$. Let $P$ be a Sylow $3$ subgroup and $Q$ a Sylow $5$ subgroup. Then the order of $N(P)$ is $54$ and the order of $N(Q)$ is $15$, so this last one is cyclic.

$N(P)$ and $N(Q)$ have an intersection of order $3.$

Here is the point where I am stuck.

The hints say to prove $45$ dividers the normalizer of this intersection and then that this fact contradicts the order of $N(Q)$ is $15.$

Any help will be very much welcomed.

Comment: Write $X=N(P)\cap N(Q)$, a subgroup of order $3$. Does $P$ normalize $X$?

Comment: Compare with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/798401/a-group-of-order-540-is-not-simple?rq=1).

Comment: By considering that 540 = 2^2 * 3^3* 5, you may use some theorems to prove it. As another approach for proof rather than yours.

Comment: I don't see why $|N(P) \cap N(Q)|$ should be equal to $3$. It could be $1$. But after fixing $Q$ you can choose $P$  to contain the subgroup of order $3$ in $N(Q)$, and then we will have $|N(P) \cap N(Q)|=3$. Let $R = N(P) \cap N(Q)$. Since $N(R)$ is properly contained in$N_P(R)$, $|N_P(R)|$ is divisible by $9$, and $|N_Q(R)|=15$, so $|N_G(R)|$ is divisible by $45$.

Comment: In reply to Derek Holt. By my reasoning, if the intersection of N(P) and N(Q) would have order 1 then N(P)N(Q) would have 810 elements. This is impossible. Still struggeling with this problem.